# search and replace enumerating found strings

Tags: python, perl, shell, text, replace

I have a huge text file (18Gb) separated by articles, each article have a heading like this:

```
<text id="1403" year="" url_source="http://www.adobe.de" error="0.008696">
```

the problem is that I should have a different id for each article, but there are some repeated ones, so what I need to do is look for the ids along the file and reenumerate them consecutively starting from 1. I've been looking around but I haven't find a suitable solution, probably because of my lack of knowledge, I would appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Is the whole file XML?

Comment: the content is like this <text id"1323".....> blah blah blah blah .....</text><text id"1323".....> blah blah blah blah .....</text>

Comment: Could you show us a little more of your file?

Comment: That sounds like you have an XML file. Use an iterative XML parser; Python has the ElementTree API with has a iterparse method.

Comment: that's chinese for me but I will look for it, thanks

Comment: why have a 18Gb txt file? binary would be more interesting for speed/diskspace? how many articles do you have like that? (is it one article-line, and than one line of text, or like 1 line and than 20 pages of text ?)

Comment: these are corpora, collection of texts to do some studies on them, thy are articles of different nature and different extension

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming id is always the first attribute of every text tag, in Perl:

```
perl -M5.010 -wpi.bak -e'our $article; s/<text id="\K[0-9]+/++$article/ge' hugetextfile
```

Note that it will rename your file with added .bak and read through it, writing out to the original name, so you need 18Gb free space.

Comment: warnings can only make noise for one liners?

Comment: you should always use warnings, even on one-liners.   strict, on the other hand...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, I will do it your way because is faster

Answer (score 1):

In python:
If it is a valid xml file, you can use an xml parser such as [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).

Otherwise, iterate over the input file and write to an output file:

```
new_id=1
with open('out_file','w') as out_f:
    with open('in_file','r') as in_f:
        for line in in_f:
            if line[:5] == '<text':
                newline = line.split(' ')
                newline[1] = "id=" + '"' + str(new_id) + '"'
                newline = ' '.join(newline)
                line = newline
                new_id += 1
            out_f.write(line)
```

Note that this assumes that each `<text ...` tag starts at the beginning of the line. If this is not the case, you have to modify it a little.